# Background image url not working when build is taken using vite

Tags: vite

Here is dist structure :

[image]

Here is src strcuture:

[image]

COnfig:

```
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import fs from "fs-extra";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  resolve: {
  alias: {
     "~bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap"),
     "~swiper": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/swiper"),
     "~select2": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/select2"),
  },
 },
 build: {
 outDir: "../dist",
 rollupOptions: {
  output: {
    assetFileNames: ({ name }) => {
      if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/.test(name ?? "")) {
        return "images/[name].[ext]";
      }

      if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? "")) {
        return "css/[name].[ext]";
      }

      if (/\.(eot|ttf|woff|svg)$/.test(name ?? "")) {
        return "fonts/[name].[ext]";
      }

      return `[name].[ext]`;
    },
    entryFileNames: `js/[name].js`,
    chunkFileNames: `js/[name].js`,
    },
   },
 },
plugins: [
  inject({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
  }),
  {
   name: "copy-assets",
  async writeBundle() {
    const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
    const outputDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");

    // Copy images directory
    await fs.copy(
      path.resolve(srcDir, "images"),
      path.resolve(outputDir, "images")
    );

    // Copy HTML files
    const files = await fs.readdir(srcDir);
    const htmlFiles = files.filter(
      (file) => path.extname(file) === ".html"
    );
    for (const file of htmlFiles) {
      const htmlSrcPath = path.resolve(srcDir, file);
      const htmlDestPath = path.resolve(outputDir, file);

      await fs.copy(htmlSrcPath, htmlDestPath);

      // Read HTML content
      let htmlContent = await fs.readFile(htmlDestPath, "utf-8");

      // Get CSS file name
      const cssFileName = "./css/index.css"; // Customize with your CSS file name
      const cssFilePath = path.relative(
        outputDir,
        path.resolve(outputDir, cssFileName)
      );

      // Add CSS file path to HTML content
      htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
        `<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />`,
        `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${cssFilePath}">`
      );

      // Get JS file name
      const jsFileName = "./js/index.js"; // Customize with your CSS file name
      const jsFilePath = path.relative(
        outputDir,
        path.resolve(outputDir, jsFileName)
      );

      // Add JS file path to HTML content
      htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
        `<script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>`,
        `<script src="${jsFilePath}"></script>`
      );

      // Write modified HTML content back to file
      await fs.writeFile(htmlDestPath, htmlContent);
    }
    },
   },
  ],
 css: {
   postcss: {
   plugins: [
    autoprefixer(), // add options if needed
   ],
  },
 },
 server: {
 port: 8080,
 hot: true,
 },
};
```

Actually the images are not working in the build, css showing the same path we have given in the scss.

in scss given the url like this :
background: url("/images/subscribe-bg.png") no-repeat bottom right;

Is there any way to change the path of the background image url on build time ?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same problem